What to do about the [wss] tag?
The wss tag is currently described as referring to "Windows SharePoint Services", but almost all of the recent questions under this tag refer to the "WebSocket Secure" (which uses wss:// urls) protocol.  I retagged a few questions before realizing the majority of the first few (at least) pages need retagging.
The tag was created back in 2011, presumably when websockets were less popular (due to only just being standardized).  But it seems to now mostly be used by people mistagging websocket questions.

wss is now renamed to windows-sharepoint-services and mistagged questions have been retagged
Questions about...

WebSocket: have been retagged to websocket
The SOAP WS-Security extension: have been retagged to ws-security
xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet": have had the tag removed without replacement
Windows Search Service: have (hopefully) been retagged to windows-search (I only saw one of these)

This is now done; thanks to those who contributed to the effort).  I've validated it by searching for [windows-sharepoint-services] -[sharepoint] -sharepoint -[sharepoint-2007] -moss.  After tagging several of these with sharepoint and retagging others per the above list1, there are 8 questions left.  A manual check confirms that they are all about Windows Sharepoint Services.
I also noticed that a few questions (no more than ~2-3 or so) that should have been tagged ws-security were mistakenly retagged to websocket.  To identify them, I searched for [websocket] is:q -websocket -socket -mqtt, sorted by active, and checked the small handful of returned questions manually.
Additionally...

The wiki excerpt has been updated to include guidance about retagging existing questions:

Windows SharePoint Services (WSS) is SharePoint Server 2007's "little" brother. It forms the basis for the full-blown server product. As of SharePoint Server 2010 it is called SharePoint Server Foundation. Questions about Websocket Secure (also WSS) should be tagged [websocket].


A synonym has been created from wss-websocket to websocket, so that if you type "wss", it will suggest the [websocket] tag.  That should probably eliminate any need to blocklist the tag.



1 ...and untagging a question ambiguously mentioning "WSS" that is not about it, as well as one probably off-topic unanswered question about Symantec Web Security Service...

I'll call the request entirely completed once there aren't quite so many mistagged questions.  Right now I estimate ~250 out of 700 are mistagged.  (someone ping me here when that happens and I'll add [status-completed])

Just to confirm, this retagging is a manual effort.  I can help out by going through and editing the remaining questions that need retagging.

@SamMason Correct, manual effort.  Any help is appreciated!

I've gone through and retagged about 150 questions, struggling to know what to look for now.  I barely know anything about sharepoint, so hope I've not misclassified!

I'm noticing a bunch that are about [tag:ws-security] also.  If it's about SOAP/WSDL, and doesn't seem to be about SharePoint (which also seems to have some SOAP APIs), it's probably about that.

I noticed those, also lots of references to libraries like wss4j which I've not used.  I assumed Sharepoint was SOAP based and hence it had been tagged wss because of that.  Hadn't thought there was another technology with the same three-letter-acronym.

WSS could also refer to Windows Storage Server. Yikes.
We should probably remove the wss tag from questions about websockets, and make sure they are tagged with the websocket tag, instead.
Additionally, it's probably a good idea to rename wss to windows-sharepoint-services. We could then blacklist the wss tag to prevent it from being recreated; at this point it could mean too many things to be of use in that unqualified acronym form.

Partial mitigation: Created a synonym from [wss-websocket] to [websocket], so that if you type "wss", it will suggest the [websocket] tag.  That should probably eliminate any need to blocklist the tag.

This looks like consensus and I'm happy to execute this rename; does anyone have an opinion on whether it should be done before or after the mistagged questions are cleaned up?

@RyanM I would say before; it will be even easier to tell whether a tag is misused once it's renamed.
